# Get full list of categories using sql

Tags: category, sql

How would I format a SQL query to get a list of all categories (id, name, and url_path) from my Magento database?

Alternatively, if you know the tables I need to do this, a list and some sort of explanation as to what I need to do would be a great help.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Using @mpaepper answer I was able to get a query that seems to be pulling the correct information back. I was able to test it on two different magento databases and each looked right. Anyway here it is.

```
  SELECT DISTINCT cc.entity_id as id, cc.value as path, cc1.value as name    
  FROM catalog_category_entity_varchar cc    
  JOIN catalog_category_entity_varchar cc1 ON cc.entity_id=cc1.entity_id    
  JOIN eav_entity_type ee ON cc.entity_type_id=ee.entity_type_id
  JOIN catalog_category_entity cce ON cc.entity_id=cce.entity_id
  WHERE cc.attribute_id = '57' AND cc1.attribute_id = '41' AND ee.entity_model = 'catalog/category';
```

I probably didn't need to join eav_entity_type but I will probably be using this query again on different versions of magento so I think this will help keep the query reusable.

Comment: Good job, to make it database independent, I would recommend also joining in the eav_attribute table to get the attribute_ids. Use attribute_code with 'name' and 'url_path' since the attribute_code will be the same between installs, the ID will not :)

Comment: i need to export from db like , sku,name,category_name, price, how can i get that

Comment: How can i get only main categories not sub-categories?

Answer (score 16):

Ok, so here are the tables and what you will need to do (I will let you do the MySQL join fun for yourself ;)):

`catalog_category_entity` is the base table which has your category ID (`entity_id`).

You then need to identify the attribute IDs for `name` and `url_path` from the table `eav_attribute`.

In my case, the `attribute_code` `name` for entity_type_id 3 (for me 3 is categories, look that up in the table eav_entity_type) has the `attribute_id`  41.
In my case, the `attribute_code` `url_path` for entity_type_id 3 has the attribute_id 57.

Both `name` and `url_path` are of type varchar, so you will find their values in `catalog_category_entity_varchar` (filter for attribute_id and entity_id where entity_id is the corresponding ID of the category).

Thus you need to use the `catalog_category_entity` table and join `catalog_category_entity_varchar` twice with the `entity_id` as join condition and specifying the attribute_ids which you can look up. Alternatively, you can do more joins, so you do not look up the IDs before, but join them in.

Have fun! :)

Comment: hey thanks for the answer, that should get the ball rolling. One question though, as you mentionted attribute_id seems like it can be different per install. Is there some logic behind what is the attribute_id or is it random.

Comment: Depending on what you're using this for, what about alternatively running a simple select against the flat category table? All 3 pieces of data are there, so if you're just looking to grab this for something like building a spreadsheet every now and then… it's far simpler and will work just as well.

Comment: it's for a drupal site that needs to use the category information. This feature will be used regularly so I would like it to be quite robust and always accurate.

Comment: @ThomasRyan The attribute_id is pretty random. It is an auto-increment key, so depending on your install, the IDs can differ significantly.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer taught me how I should observe the Magento database.

Answer (score 6):

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT cc.entity_id as category_id, cc.value as name, cc1.value as 
url_path ,cce.parent_id as parent_id ,0 as top,level as `column`,position as 
sort_order,1 as status,created_at as date_added,updated_at as date_modified 

FROM catalog_category_entity_varchar cc 
JOIN catalog_category_entity_varchar cc1 ON cc.entity_id=cc1.entity_id   
JOIN catalog_category_entity_int cc_int ON cc1.entity_id=cc_int.entity_id   
JOIN eav_entity_type ee ON cc.entity_type_id=ee.entity_type_id JOIN catalog_category_entity cce ON cc.entity_id=cce.entity_id 
WHERE cc.attribute_id in (select attribute_id from eav_attribute where attribute_code ='name') AND cc1.attribute_id in (select attribute_id from eav_attribute where attribute_code ='url_path')
and cc_int.attribute_id in (select attribute_id from eav_attribute where attribute_code ='is_active')
and cc_int.value = 1
and ((cce.parent_id = 2 and cce.children_count > 1) or cce.parent_id > 2)       
AND ee.entity_model = 'catalog/category' order by cce.parent_id asc, 
cce.position asc;
```

Comment: @ arun : how can i export category name instead of category id

Comment: @JeevaRathinam cc1.value as title contains category name

Comment: @arun-jamhub : how to export sku, category path(name not id)

Answer (score 5):

To get all main category use the below query

```
select *
  from catalog_category_flat_store_1
  where level = 2 and
        is_active = 1
  order by parent_id asc, position asc;
```

Change the level accordingly

Comment: This does not work if you don't have the flat categories flag set to yes or if you don't have a website with id 1

Comment: @Marius You are correct if flat is not set to yes, we have to use something  like below select a.*,b.* from catalog_category_entity a, catalog_category_entity_varchar b where a.entity_id = b.entity_id and b.attribute_id in (select attribute_id from eav_attribute where entity_type_id = 9 and (attribute_code = "name" or attribute_code = "image")) and level =2 order by parent_id asc, position asc

Answer (score 1):

In Magento 2, entity_type_id is not available in catalog_category_entity_varchar table, so I have to google and find the intermediate table,eav_attribute, to get what I need.  Entity_id is also replace with row_id in Magento 2

```
SELECT DISTINCT cc.row_id as category_id, cc.value as image, cc1.value as 
title, cce.parent_id as parent_id, 0 as top, level as `column`, position as 
sort_order, 1 as status,created_at as date_added, updated_at as date_modified 

FROM catalog_category_entity_varchar cc 
JOIN catalog_category_entity_varchar cc1 ON cc.row_id=cc1.row_id   
JOIN catalog_category_entity_int cc_int ON cc1.row_id=cc_int.row_id 
join eav_attribute as att on att.`attribute_id` = cc.`attribute_id`
JOIN eav_entity_type ee ON att.entity_type_id=ee.entity_type_id JOIN catalog_category_entity cce ON cc.row_id=cce.row_id 
WHERE cc.attribute_id in (select distinct attribute_id from eav_attribute where attribute_code ='name')
   AND cc1.attribute_id in (select attribute_id from eav_attribute where attribute_code ='url_path')
AND cc_int.attribute_id in (select attribute_id from eav_attribute where attribute_code ='is_active')
AND cc_int.value = 1
AND ((cce.parent_id = 2 and cce.children_count > 1) or cce.parent_id > 2)       
AND ee.entity_model = 'Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category'
order by cce.parent_id asc, 
cce.position asc;
```

I want to thank you all to help me get what I need. :)

Answer (score 1):

To get Magento category data directly from the data base, I use this:

```
select
   p.entity_id  as entity_id,

   if(pp.level = 1,
      n.value,
      concat_ws (' / ', pn.value, n.value)) as name,

   date(p.created_at) as created_at

from
   catalog_category_entity p

   -- name
   left join catalog_category_entity_varchar n on
      p.entity_id = n.entity_id and n.attribute_id = 41

   -- status
   left join catalog_category_entity_int s on
      p.entity_id = s.entity_id and s.attribute_id = 42 and
      s.store_id = 0

   -- parent
   left join catalog_category_entity pp on p.parent_id = pp.entity_id

   -- parent name
   left join catalog_category_entity_varchar pn on
      pp.entity_id = pn.entity_id and pn.attribute_id = 41 and
      pn.store_id = 0

where
   s.value = 1 and -- status is active
   p.level >= 2 

order by
   2
;
```

Attribute_ids differ from system to system.  Here I'm using 41, and 42.

In order to determine the correct attribute_ids for category name and category status from a Magento site, I use:

```
select
   p.entity_id,
   a.attribute_id,
   a.frontend_label as attribute,
   av.value

from
   catalog_category_entity p

   left join catalog_category_entity_{datatype} av on
      p.entity_id = av.entity_id

   left join eav_attribute a on
      av.attribute_id = a.attribute_id

where
   p.entity_id = {eid}
;
```

By substitute {datatype} with 'varchar' you can get the attribute_id for category name, and with 'int' to get the attribute_id for category status.  You can substitute {eid} for any category entity_id.

This can be done in an editor or on the command line with sed like so:

Assuming wdb is an alias set to your website mysql database connection like this:

```
alias wdb='mysql -h<hostname> -u<username> -p<password> <databasename>'
```

Then you can run

```
$ cat show_category_attr.sql | sed -e "s/{datatype}/varchar/" -e "s/{eid}/2/" | wdb -t
```

And get

```
+-----------+--------------+--------------+------------------+
| entity_id | attribute_id | attribute    | value            |
+-----------+--------------+--------------+------------------+
|         2 |           41 | Name         | Default Category |
|         2 |           49 | Display Mode | PRODUCTS         |
+-----------+--------------+--------------+------------------+
```

And run

```
$ cat show_category_attr.sql | sed -e "s/{datatype}/int/" -e "s/{eid}/2/"| wdb -t
```

And get

```
+-----------+--------------+----------------------------+-------+
| entity_id | attribute_id | attribute                  | value |
+-----------+--------------+----------------------------+-------+
|         2 |           42 | Is Active                  |     1 |
|         2 |           67 | Include in Navigation Menu |     1 |
+-----------+--------------+----------------------------+-------+
```

Here you can see the necessary numbers 41 and 42.

The same technique can be used for Magento Products.

Answer (score 1):

For Magento 2.
To get a full list of category names along with their IDs and URL Paths:

```
SELECT entity_id AS "CATEGORY ID", ccev1.value as "CATEGORY NAME", CONCAT(ccev2.value, ".html") AS "CATEGORY PATH"
FROM catalog_category_entity AS cce
JOIN catalog_category_entity_varchar AS ccev1 USING (entity_id)
JOIN catalog_category_entity_varchar AS ccev2 USING (entity_id)
JOIN eav_attribute AS ea1 ON ea1.attribute_id = ccev1.attribute_id
JOIN eav_attribute AS ea2 ON ea2.attribute_id = ccev2.attribute_id
WHERE ea1.attribute_code = 'name' AND ea1.entity_type_id = 3 AND ea2.attribute_code = 'url_path'
ORDER BY entity_id
```

This is ordered by Category ID.
If you want to order it by name change "ORDER BY entity_id" to "ORDER BY ccev1.value".